# "Your device is managed by your organization. Administrators can access..." issue on the chrome on my personal PC

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, window, software-update, hp

My Chrome shows this message whenever I try to create a new profile. It's my personal laptop and not attached to any organisation. I have attempted almost all the solutions online to no avail. I want to be sure someone is not spying on me or my device is not hacked. If it helps, my PC is using Windows 11 Pro.

These are the solutions I've tried;

- Reset Chrome through settings, checked chrome Policy and extensions, nothing found
- I have tried `RD /S /Q “%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers”` and the response I got is "The system cannot find the file specified"
- I have deleted Google folder from AppUser and also uninstalled chrome and some other applications
- I have tried to locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies` on my system. However, chrome is not available in the Policy.
- I've scanned PC with an antivirus.

After doing all these multiple times, the problem remains the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does `chrome://management/` show?

Comment: It says "This browser is not managed by a company or other organization. Activity on this device may be managed outside of Chrome. Learn more"

Comment: "I want to be sure someone is not spying on me or my device is not hacked." - This absolutely is not happening.

Comment: I want to believe that. This situation is daunting.

Comment: @Kdott - This is a configuration problem.  Your system had not been compromised.  You are not even looking for the existence of Google Chrome group policies. There was a change in Chrome 73 from 2019, which cause some third-party software, to cause this message to be displayed.  That is the most likely explaination.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Like I mentioned, I have tried searching for Google or Chrome in both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies and I have also tried using the command prompt, the result is in the screenshot. What else do you think I can do or look at?

Edited. I have read your response, do you reckon I pretend the message is not there and continue using chrome as usual?

Comment: There was malware back in 2019 that would cause this behavior with Chrome.  I would spin up a free Windows 11 VM, install Chrome, and see if the problem surfaces within the VM.  When you deleted the Chrome directory within AppUser did you make sure you deleted the Chrome user profile you are using (after you made sure to back it up)? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft` would have nothing to do with a Google Chrome group policy

Comment: I backed up my chrome profiles, signed out my gmail, deleted chrome directory and then uninstall chrome. At the moment, no Gmail is signed in but yet the message is there. I'm trying to look into Windows WV, that one is a new one to me.

And yeah, I mean, there is Microsoft Policy on there but nothing looks like Chrome.

Comment: I have no idea what "Windows WV" is.  Depending which Google directory you deleted you might not have deleted the profile directory.  What is the path to the user profile and did you delete that directory?

Comment: This is the path for the item I deleted "C:\Users\Kdott\AppData\Local\Google" . I also deleted "C:\ProgramData\Google"